# c - netmap - Tun/tap vs netmap/pf_ring/dpdk

Tags: networking, tcp, c, stack

Would a Tun/tap device avoid a netmap/pf_ring/dpdk installation ? If tun/tap allow to bypass kernel, isn't it the same thing ?

Or those codes bring so many optimizations that they overclass tun os bypass strategy ?

The final goal is to port tcp/ip from kernel to user space, FOR TESTING PURPOSES.

I don't quite understand here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no. 
for userspace tcpip implementation see lwip or rumpkernel. 
dpdk/pfring/netmap as you probably know are about getting packets to userspace as fast as possible.
tun/tap are virtual interface things. probably not what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Tun/tap are not particularly performant. They miss out on the IP stack, but there is a lot of copying still involved. Profile some code using them to see. I think the best option for straight userspace networking is probably AF_PACKET using the ring buffer option, but that will is still an indirect ring buffer that gets copied to the network card ring buffer rather than being direct like you get with solutions like dpdk. It depends on your performance requirements - if it is just for testing correctness any solution should be fine.